# Название нашей планеты

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Сразу прошу прощения за дурацкий вопрос. Но меня всегда интересовало, почему и когда было решено называть нашу планету Земля?

Comment: А можно чуть уточнить вопрос?  
Вряд ли кто-то что-то тут "решал".  
Или Вас интересует омонимичность названия планеты и её твердой поверхности?

Comment: >― Дурак, ― засмеялись Зюнчик и Колька, ― Земля название земли, а Одесса название Одессы.
  
Аркадий Львов. Двор (1981)

Comment: "Это мое последнее сообщение" - сказал дерзкий. (С)Я

Comment: *Молчи, грусть, молчи*

Comment: "Я солгал" (С) Дерзкий

Comment: "--  Нет, нет, игемон, -- весь напрягаясь  в  желании убедить, заговорил
 арестованный,  --  ходит,  ходит один с  козлиным  пергаментом  и непрерывно
 пишет. Но я однажды заглянул в этот пергамент и ужаснулся. Решительно ничего
 из того, что там написано, я не  говорил.  Я его  умолял: сожги ты бога ради
 свой пергамент! Но он вырвал его у меня из рук и убежал."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересно, а когда древние говорили о том, что Земля стоит на трех китах, они каким   термином пользовались?
Я думаю, что первична Земля как планета, твердь земная. 
Без этого невозможна никакая космогония, а это первое, чем занимается древний человек, отвлекшись от повседневных забот.

Comment: Я  думаю,  что  задолго  до  того,  когда  человек  создал  первый  космогонический  миф,  он  уже  знал,  как  называется  то,  по  чему  он  ходит.

Comment: Не буду спорить насчет "задолго", но как минимум "не позже того".

Comment: Да,  сначала  гео,  потом  Гея !

Answer (score 2):

Я  думаю,  что  цепочка  здесь  такая: земля - почва,  земля - область,  земля - вся  суша (  весь  мир ),  а  когда  определили,  что  всё  это  ещё  и  небесное  тело ( планета ),  то  планета  Земля.

Comment: Раньше слово *земля* писали со строчной, но имелась в виду именно планета :  
В. Н. Татищев. Разговор двух приятелей о пользе науки и училищах (1733) Подлинно же известие имеем о Пифагоре, что в арифметике, геометрии и астрономии немалое основание имел и едва не первой ли начал разсуждать, что **земля около солнца идет**...

Паче же ужасно от гистории видим...  бо высокаго ума и науки людей невинно тем оклеветанных и проклятию от пап преданных, как то Вергилий епискуп за учение, что **земля шаровидна**; Коперникус за то, что написал **земля около солнца, а месяц около земли ходит**...